# Pairwise combinations of two image stacks

Tags: python, combinations, numpy-ndarray, combinatorics

I have 2 RGB image stacks containing 200 images each. Each image is (300, 300, 3) so each stack is (200, 300, 300, 3).

So we have:

```
a_stack[200, 300, 300, 3]
b_stack[200, 300, 300, 3]
```

My aim is to calculate the Euclidean distance between every pairwise combination of images in each stack, which I can do using

`measure = dist.euclidean(a_img.flatten(), b_img.flatten())`

My problem is constructing the appropriate iterator to get every pairwise combination between `a_stack` and `b_stack`

I had a look at [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) but this appeared to be for combinations of elements in strings. Is there a similar thing for narrays?

Comment: The itertools functions typically apply to any iterable, not just strings. The expression `for a, b in itertools.combinations(a_stack, b_stack)` should hence work fine. However, from your description it seems you are looking for `itertools.product`, not `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen given that the arrays are 4D will that only create products over the 1st dimension?

Comment: Yes, the iterator applies to the first dimension. (Aside: the `itertools.combinations` statement above is incorrect; my mind was already thinking about the cartesian product, for which the statement is correct).